# Updating an MS Access table in C#

Tags: c#, ms-access, ado.net

I'm working with a Microsoft Access Database in my Winforms project. I'm using OLEDB to connect. I have the following table I'm trying to update:

```
    TotalLogins
--------------------
ID        AutoNumber
TokenNo   Text
UserID    Number
FromDate  DateTime //Contains datetime of login
ToDate    DateTime //Contains datetime of logout
```

How do I write C# code that updates this table with all the required information?

Comment: Have you tried a search for c# and ms-access tags : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23+ms-access ? It will allow you to get enough information to post a question with some code.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code as example

```
OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(conString);
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE TotalLogins SET TokenNo=@TokenNo, UserID=@UserID, FromDate=@FromDate, ToDate=@ToDate WHERE ID=@ID";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TokenNo", varTokenNo);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", varUserID);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FromDate", varFromDate);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ToDate", varToDate);
            cn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cn.Close();
```